# Mysql insert,on duplicate key update with subquery null issue

Tags: mysql

I have a confusing problem. My query like this;

```
insert into simple_products
(Product_Id,attribute,quantity,Barcode) 
values ((select id from products where sku='180 JK101G' and attribute='4621'),26,2,1068215)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
attribute=values(attribute),
quantity=values(quantity),
Barcode=values(Barcode)
```

But sometimes subquery returns nothing. So I want then do nothing but I can't find any solution.

Is there a way for this?

Comment: Lose the brackets and put ,26,2,1068215 inside the select query.

Try this

insert into simple_products
(Product_Id,attribute,quantity,Barcode) 
values (select id,26,2,1068215 from products where sku='180 JK101G' and attribute='4621')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
attribute=values(attribute),
quantity=values(quantity),
Barcode=values(Barcode)

Comment: Yes its works but a litle change;

Comment: insert into simple_products (Product_Id,attribute,quantity,Barcode) select id,26 as a,2 as b ,1068215 as c from products where sku='180 JK101G' and attribute='4621' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE attribute=values(attribute), quantity=values(quantity), Barcode=values(Barcode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [insert ... select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)

```
insert 
  into simple_products (Product_Id, attribute, quantity, Barcode)        

       select id, 26, 2, 1068215 
         from products 
        where sku='180 JK101G' 
          and attribute='4621'

    on duplicate key update
       attribute=values(attribute),
       quantity=values(quantity),
       Barcode=values(Barcode);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's solved thanks to @IvanM

```
    insert into simple_products (Product_Id,attribute,quantity,Barcode) 
select id,26 as a,2 as b ,1068215 as c from products where sku='180 JK101G' and attribute='4621' 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE attribute=values(attribute), quantity=values(quantity), Barcode=values(Barcode)
```